# "<< / >>" Operators in C++

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

So since I can't find anything on Google due to them somehow not accepting the search term ">>", I decided to ask here.

First of, no I do not mean the bitwise shift operator. This is different. I've seen it occur in some code and it would make no sense if it was a shift operator.

`cout << a;` would be an example. I know it prints out a, but what is the definition of "<<"?

Or in my case, I have a code similar to this:

```
for(int index=0;index<n;index++)
    inputFile >> StringArray[index];
```

What does it mean?

Comment: they are called stream operators, used to put in or take out data from the IO streams.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bitshift operator is frequently overloaded to mean reading values from and writing to streams.

Edit: In slightly more detail, C++ lets you overload, or change the meaning of, almost any operator. The `<<` and `>>` operators were chosen to be overloaded for writing/reading to a source or sink of data because they visually look like arrows or conduits. There is zero commonality with shifting bits except as to what operator is used.

Comment: Please explain in more detail.

Comment: Are you familiar with operator overloading?

Comment: @BannanaCode: More info on operator overloading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: Ah yes, I'm familiar with operator overloading. I was more curious as to how the streaming operator works in combination with the for-loop. How much gets streamed? What happens when the stream goes empty?

Comment: @BananaCode see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/ . Look at the description and the return values.

Answer (score 1):

They are bitwise shifting overloaded operators, usually called 'stream operators'
I don't know it in detail but as you said,

```
cout<<a;
```

outputs the value of a, that is it puts the value of a into the output stream which get displayed on the screen.

And in the case of

```
inputfile>>variable;
```

You are reading the data from the file into the variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's about writing to or reading from streams.

Check this out for a practical example: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files and http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/filestreams.pdf‎.

Answer (score 1):

These are called bitwise operators, as you said.

However, in C++ you can overload these operators (in fact any operator) to do what you want them to. This is what is happening here. The `<<` and `>>` are overloaded in the `ostream` and `istream` objects, to print to and read from a stream, respectively.

In fact you could overload any operator to do whatever you want on an object. An example can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/).

Cheers.

PS: The concept around these operators is easily visualized. When you write:

```
cout << "Hello world";
```

with a little bit of imagination, you could say that you "put" the string on the right to the `cout` stream on the left (thus the left directed "arrows"). Same, when you write:

```
std::string str;
cin >> str;
```

you could imagine that you extract a string from the `cin` stream on the left and "put" it on the `str` variable on the right (thus the right directed "arrows").